# view the values for unsupported data type in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a type including a map member function in Oracle live.

```
select value(r),r.rid
from rectangle r;
```

When I executed the above one it will display [unsupported data type] as the value(r) column output. How I can view the real data in it? Because that value is important in map member function to compare.

```
create type rectangle_t as object(
  rid varchar(2),
  lengths number,
  width number
);
ALTER type rectangle_t add map member function area return number cascade;
create or replace type body rectangle_t map member function area return number is
  BEGIN
    return self.lengths*self.width;
  END;
END;
create table rectangle of rectangle_t;
INSERT INTO rectangle VALUES('a',10,5);
INSERT INTO rectangle VALUES('b',20,10);
INSERT INTO rectangle VALUES('c',5,2);
```

[image]

Comment: Show the type you created

Comment: I have updated the question with it

Comment: The problem is  with Livesql. It worked perfectly fine for me in SQL developer. You can download Oracle / sqldeveloper for free and install on your machine and try this.

Comment: Will it work with sqlplus?

Comment: Actually I need to sort it in descending order according to area. How can I do it?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know.  Also, in ur question "as"keyword is missing in `create or replace type body rectangle_t...`      correct it

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment.

> Actually I need to sort it in descending order according to area. How
>   can I do it?

You can use this.

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    r.area() area
FROM
    rectangle r
ORDER BY
    area DESC;
```

**O/p**

```
RI    LENGTHS      WIDTH       AREA
-- ---------- ---------- ----------
b          20         10        200
a          10          5         50
c           5          2         10
```

The problem is with Livesql. It worked perfectly fine for me in `SQL developer`. You can download Oracle for free and install on your machine and try this in sql developer or `sqlplus`.